# An App ID with identifier '--' is not available. please enter a different string

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My certificate has expired, I created a new one using XCODE. Ever since that, When I tried to install my application on my development phone I see No matching provisioning profiles found error. when I hit fix issue button right below the error. It is giving me An App ID with identifier '--' is not available, please enter a different string. It looks like I am conflicting with my own  name I created for this application.

would deleting my app ID from https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle help? or Am I missing a simple step before I take that route? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In Xcode, open preferences (Xcode > Preferences)
2. Select your account
3. Click on view details
4. Delete all provision profiles for that app
5. Restart Xcode
6. Download them again and run your application

Follow theses steps and it should work for you.